# How to clear stored substitution variables in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I have a query:

```
SELECT * from table1 tr where tr.start_time < &&starttime;
```

First time i execute the query, SQL Developer prompts me to enter the value for the substitution variable 'starttime' and is stored. Next time I run the script, it reuses the same value again, how do I reset/clear the stored value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UNDEFINE starttime;
```

Just use above command.

Answer (score 4):

Just use one ampersand at the start.  You will be prompted to enter the value fresh. [See the difference between & and &&](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.26_and_.26.26.3F)

Answer (score 2):

You can try these commands:

```
select &&v_value from table_name;
undefine v_value;
```